# Preform Multplication within a Scss Each

Tags: foreach, sass, each, increment, multiplication

Does anyone know how to implement a multiplication on my left css value.

Current code:

```
$no-of-heading-elements:(1,2);

@each $nav-list-no in $no-of-heading-elements{
    $value:-194px;

    [data-nav="#{$nav-list-no}"].secondry-header-block &{
        left: $value;
    }
}
```

Each left css value should be:

```
[data-nav="1"].secondry-header-block .secondary-sub-header {
  left: -194px;
}
[data-nav="2"].secondry-header-block .secondary-sub-header {
  left: -(194px * 2);
}
```

Current output:

```
[data-nav="1"].secondry-header-block .secondary-sub-header {
  left: -194px;
}
[data-nav="2"].secondry-header-block .secondary-sub-header {
  left: -194px;
}
```

Desired Ouput:

```
[data-nav="1"].secondry-header-block .secondary-sub-header {
  left: -194px;
}
[data-nav="2"].secondry-header-block .secondary-sub-header {
  left: -388px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  You understand that you need to perform multiplication, but you're not doing it in the Sass?

Comment: I would like the multiplication to be run when it cycles through each number inside the each loop.

Comment: So do it?  I still don't see the problem.

Comment: I dont see the point in doing the math if I am using an each loop (otherwise all the classes will have the same value). I want the loop to count though, which it is. However I want the left value (-194px) to be multiplied by the corresponding number in the loop. E.g. ($no-of-heading-elements) contains 6 then left would be multiplied by 6. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the math inside the loop, otherwise you just get the same value generated with each pass.

```
$no-of-heading-elements:(1,2);

@each $nav-list-no in $no-of-heading-elements{
    $value: 194px;

    [data-nav="#{$nav-list-no}"].secondry-header-block {
        left: -($value * $nav-list-no); // starts with -194px
        left: -($value * ($nav-list-no - 1)); // starts with 0
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks was missing some syntax

Comment: I have just noticed that it starts from -194, what amends would be needed to count it from zero, I would prefer not to start from zero.

Comment: You *do* or *do not* want to start from 0?  Your desired sample output indicates that you want it to start at -194 (which is what this compiles to).

Comment: I would like the the output of [data-nav="1"] to be 0 but [data-nav="2"] to be -194

Comment: I've added an example for that

Comment: thanks @cimmanon, amazing what you can achieve when questions are explained properly :)